# NSUrl connection to some local network-no respond

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to connect to some local network of mine (hardware ).
So i find the network on the iPhone settings, and connect to it .
Now , i am trying to send a simple request to that access point .

The access point does getting my request, and send back respond, problem is, i never get the respond on the device.

If i try to send the request using Chrome browser on my mac , i do get the respond "hello world" , but not on the device.

I have tried synchronise and un-synchronise requests, non of which give me nothing. they do although send the request . what am i missing ?

**sync:**

```
  NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.x.x/data:moredata"]];
    NSURLResponse * response = nil;
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSData * tdata = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                          returningResponse:&response
                                                      error:&error];

    NSLog(@"-%@",tdata);
```

**and async**, delegates are not being called :(did register for them with `<NSURLConnectionDelegate`  )

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ [NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]   ;
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.x.x/data:datax"]];



         NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO  ];
        [conn scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
                              forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [conn start];





- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"+%@",response);
    _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
     NSLog(@"-%@",data);
    [_responseData appendData:data];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
     return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
     NSLog(@"DO");

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
     NSLog(@"FAILEDERR");

}
```

Comment: may be the reason local host calls , try online server

Comment: What?? i dont understand your sentence..

Comment: Have you read the question ? i have tried with a browser and it worked.

Comment: There are might be a lot of reasons on why is this not happening, for example your computer is connected to the network with cable being in the same sub network as an access point, and device is connected by wi-fi being in the different network. Try to run it on emulator, also try this link in the mobile Safari on device.

Comment: also try this    ` [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
    completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
    {     /*  @todo: check result  */    }];`

Comment: @teamnorge thanks, the connection is being made, as i wrote, the receiver gets the data from the iPhone, but the respond data on the iPhone is not happening.

Comment: no respond even in the simulator. only in a browser i get the respond.

Comment: @Curnelious try to put a breakpoint inside the completionHandler function in my example and see if it's called. I would proceed with async one, and the example you shown is just fine, but there are might be some problems that you have not assigned your class delegate to listen or something like that, with that approach you do not need to do it. Then you can also increase the default timeout in your request in the way: ` NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
       timeoutInterval:60];`

Comment: the completion handler is  being called, i have added a log inside it and its printing null for the data after a while. the class is register to the delegate with NSObject<NSURLConnectionDelegate